# Compare Two Files with duplicate input value

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, awk

I am having the following two files

## BC.txt

```
"PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
"PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
```

## PB.txt

```
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
```

I am trying to compare Col1 of BC.txt with Col12 of PB.txt and print the matches next to each other. For same value in col1 of BC.txt has different value in col2 and Col3. So while comparing I am getting output for only one entry of BC.txt. But I want for all.

```
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NR==FNR {a[$1]=($2" "$3);next} $12 in a {print $0,a[$12]}' BC.txt PB.txt
```

## Expected Output

```
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
```

I want to compare all the entries of BC.txt with that of PB.txt; but since its the same value my code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about output line order compared to the expected output in your question then read BC.txt into memory as it's briefer:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$1,++cnt[$1]] = $2 OFS $3
    next
}
{
    for (c=1; c<=cnt[$12]; c++) {
        print $0, map[$12,c]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk BC.txt PB.txt
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
```

but if you do care then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$12,++cnt[$12]] = $0
    next
}
{
    for (c=1; c<=cnt[$1]; c++) {
        print map[$1,c], $2, $3
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk PB.txt BC.txt
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AGCGGCCT; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  tr  41258945    41270445    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41258945    41259026    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41259626    41259754    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
c4  PB  Ex  41262664    41262814    .   +   .   g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10"; UMI=AAGCGGCC; BC=TTTCAGCGCCGA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `join` to do this? (if the columns were sorted, or <() through `sort`.

```
$ join BC.txt <(awk '{print $12,$0}' PB.txt) | cut -d' ' -f 4-
c4 PB tr 41258945 41270445 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41258945 41259026 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41259626 41259754 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41262664 41262814 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB tr 41258945 41270445 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41258945 41259026 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41259626 41259754 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
c4 PB Ex 41262664 41262814 . + . g_i "PB.50262"; t_i "PB.50262.10";
```

and cut/awk the columns you want out of the join?

Comment: You'd need to add "sort"s in for each file too since join requires sorted input. Join was my first thought too but then when you need to sort the inputs and then pipe to awk to select/reorder fields it just didn't seem like the right approach. Maybe it is though, idk.

Comment: I think for small files the awk two pass works a treat. I'm used to bioinformatics files where we never have enough RAM for anything.

Comment: @dr-who Join is great and helpfull; but since I need to sort the file I lost the order (which sometime important). So, I was looking for an awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(tested with your provided samples only).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  b[count]=$12
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    split(a[i],array," ")
    if($1==array[12]){
       print a[i],$2,$3
    }
  }
}'  PB.txt BC.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when PB.txt is being read.
  a[++count]=$0               ##Creating an array named a whose index is variable count with incrment value of 1 and value is current line.
  b[count]=$12                ##Creating an array named b whose  index is variabe count and value if 12th column.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){      ##Starting a for loop from here from i=1 to till value of count.
    split(a[i],array," ")     ##Splitting value of a[i] into array named array whose delimiter is space.
    if($1==array[12]){        ##Checking condition if $1 is equal to array[12] then do following.
       print a[i],$2,$3       ##Printing array a value along with 2nd and 3rd column value.
    }
  }
}'  PB.txt BC.txt             ##Mentioning Input_files names here.
```

Comment: Both my files are large. Its still running. But initial output indicating its working perfectly as I want.

Comment: How large they are? Yes, it will take time since a loop is running on each line. I didn't consider that files are large so tested and created it with provided samples. Kindly do post if in case of any queries, I will answer it in morning, it's quite late night here :)

Comment: That will be extremely slow since for every line of BC.txt it's looping through every line of PB.txt and doing field splitting again on that line from PB.txt. Also - I don't see `b[]` being used after it's initialized.